# Как сделать самовызывающуюся рекурсивную стрелочную функцию?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

написал вот такой код:

```js
(function doCount(i) {
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (i < 100) {
      doCount(++i);
    }
  }, 15)
}(0))
```

но не нравится "function" хочется как то покороче покрасивее))
может быть даже избавиться от именования.

Comment: Если вы хотите при этом уложится в одно выражение, то вам понадобится `Y-combinator`. А так `function <name> ...` позволяет определить имя и сразу его использовать. Это такой трюк в JavaScript. Без него нужны два оператора: определение функции и её вызов (или Y-combinator).

Comment: короче и, тем более, красивее не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот аналог на стрелочных функциях. Его пришлось завернуть в анонимную функцию чтобы не засорять глобальное пространство имен:

```
(() => {
    const doCount = i => {
        console.log(i);
        if (i < 100) {
            setTimeout(() => doCount(i + 1), 15);
        }
    };
    doCount(0);
})();
```

Не очень красиво. Но [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) позволяет именовать и вызывать функцию в одном операторе. Для стрелочных функций такого сервиса нет: чтобы использовать имя функции в рекурсивном вызове, определение функции должно быть присвоено какой-то переменной. Громоздко.

Безымянный рекурсивный вызов делается с помощью [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). Идея в том что передать в функцию её саму в качестве аргумента. Тогда её можно вызывать рекурсивно, не ссылаясь ни на какие глобальные имена:

```
((f, i) => f(f, i))((f, i) => {
    console.log(i);
    if (i < 100) {
        setTimeout(() => f(f, i + 1), 15);
    }
}, 0);
```

Если предыдущий код кажется запутанным, вот его расшифровка с глобальными именами. Так будет проще разобраться. Важное: каждое глобальное имя в коде используется только один раз, что позволяет все три оператора собрать в один как в предыдущем примере:

```
const YCombinator = (f, i) => f(f, i);

const doCount = (f, i) => {
    console.log(i);
    if (i < 100) {
        setTimeout(() => f(f, i + 1), 15);
    }
};

YCombinator(doCount, 0);
```